# Rails Nested models in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

How do I properly nest the event pictures in the event index so that way when event_pictures are posted they can be viewed?

Here is my model

```
class EventPicture < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :event
end
```

I am using fields for in my form

```
 <%= f.fields_for :event_picture, @event.event_picture do |ff| %>

  <p>
    <%= ff.label :name  %><br>
    <%= ff.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%=ff.label :url %>
    <%=ff.text_field :url %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
```

Here is my event view (index):

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div class = "admincreate">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <p> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= link_to 'New event' , new_event_path(@events)%> </button> </p>
  </div>
<% end %>


    <% @events.each do |event| %>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <div class =".btn-group-xs">
      <tr>
        <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= link_to 'Show', event_path(event) %> </button>  </td>
        <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %> </button> </td>
        <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= link_to 'Delete',event_path(event),
                      method: :delete,
                      data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %> </button></td>
        </div>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
</table>
<% end %>

<table>
<% @events.each do |event| %>
<tr>
        <td class = "content-overlap-right">
        <h1 class = "eventtitle"> <h1><%= event.title%> </h1>
        <p class = "eventlink"><b> <%= event.url %></b></p>
        <p class = "eventbody"><%= event.body%> </p>
        </td>
</tr>
<%end%>
</table>
```

here is my controller

```
def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:title, :url, :body, event_picture_attributes:
        [:id, :url, :name])
    end
```

I've tried 1) event_pictures.URL (in my `@events.each do`) & I've tried event pictures each do.

Maybe I missed a small detail or have been way off , but I am a little confused about displaying nested attributes in general.

Thanks for any help!

edit: My final intention is that the associated event_picture will delete when events are deleted - as well as having the event picture show up with each posted event. I assume there is a `@event_picture.each do` involved but it is not very straightforward seeming (since of course, it has to be the associated event picture already).

if anyone does answer I'll do my best to make the answer clear to others as well.

edit:
Here are my routes.rb

`resources :events do
    resources :event_pictures, shallow: true
  end`

Comment: Why do you ask “if user_signed_in” inside “if user_signed_in” inside “if user_signed_in”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the picture for an event:

```
<%= image_tag event.event_picture.url ... %>
```

To destroy pictures, in Event model:

```
has_one :event_picture, :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment: <%= image_tag event.event_picture.url %> - in proper ruby tags then ?

Comment: My linked pictures now display just fine ! thank you !

Comment: Yes. I wrote in my phone and forgot the %. Added

Comment: I didn't mean to sound silly or anything about it! Thanks for the answer!. I'm wondering how to make them work with bootstrap now, but I think some googling around / docs should do it.

Comment: You can add bootstrap classes such as “img-responsive”, “col-xs-12” etc.

Comment: ` <%= image_tag (event.event_picture.url, class: 'image-overlap') %>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want the nested resources to be destroyed as well when you destroy the event object, add `:_delete` to the `event_picture_attributes` .

For nested resources to work properly, Please declare the routes and create the forms using rails form builder.

Follow these tutorials and tell me if you face any problem.

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources
>
> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: so add :_delete in the controller ? 

`private
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:title, :url, :body, event_picture_attributes:
        [:id, :url, :name, :_delete]) - assuming this is correct 
    end
end
`

Comment: yes, and do follow the above tutorials to define the routes correctly and build a nested form correctly.

Comment: Okay, I will edit and update as I go and when I'm stuck I will add another comment - my nested form is actually showing the pictures (It's just the index.html that is) but I will look through that resource more.

Comment: Okay so I have an event model and an event pictures model. event has one event picture. and event picture belongs to event.